# Parse HTML inside renderUI

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to parse HTML inside renderUI. I tried below code, but it is taking as character and not a HTML. Basically, "Next Line" should be displayed in the next line?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderUI({
    paste0("Filtered value are for ", as.character(br()),"Next line")
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `renderUI` rather than `renderText`...

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderText({
    paste0("Filtered value are for ", br(),"Next line")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Gives

[image]

If you do need to use `renderUI`,

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderUI({
    tagList("Filtered value are for ", br(),"Next line")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

gives the same result.